# is it possible that I can set the website so that it autosizes?

Tags: css, autosize

I am creating a website that is 800x800. i want to code the website so that when a user visits my website, the window automatically scales down to 800x800. is this possible by using dreamweaver (css)?

Comment: Do you want to resize the browser's window? This is not advisable. Just align your website in the center/ middle of the document.

Comment: Paypal does this for payments sometimes. I want to stab it in the face with a spork. Please don't resize browser windows. Centering it horizontally and vertically, with a nice background image, is a much more elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `resizeTo` method. Check out the implementation here:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/resizing.htm

But *I don't think what you are doing is good practice* in the sense that you are resizing the users' window without they doing it on their own.

With following bit of CSS, you can create `800x800` layout instead:

```
#container{
  width:800px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Where `#container` is assumed to be the main container tag for your site.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by container. can you please explain to me what exactly it is? sorry, im new to this.

Comment: @ Ken W create a div with the id value set to container and wrap all of your content inside of it.  By setting a fixed width and the margins to auto you will ensure that your content remains in the center of the page

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. It's blocked in most modern browsers because resizing the browser window is a major nuisance for the user.

Create your web site in a way that works in a normal window instead, e.g. by defining a 800 x 800 pixels large container that is centered in the browser window.

Alternatively, you can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) to open a 800 x 800 pixel popup, but it will contain the address bar, and will be blocked by pop-up blockers.

Comment: well, this is what im doing: on the homepage i have a "copyright" link on the bottom. when you click it, a small window will popup containing further details of the copyright info. when the user clicks on the popup, the popup disappears. I would like to know how I can auto re-size the popup so that the popup will not be a super huge window covering the homepage.

Comment: @Ken W why not use an inline dialog like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/? So much less trouble...

Comment: unfortunately we're not allowed to use javascript.. yet. our instructor told us that we were only allowed to use css or html.. any idea how this could be done by using css and/or html?

Comment: @Ken there is no way to resize a window without using JavaScript.